# Successfully installed modules in Python 3.8 using Pip but I can't import them?

Tags: python, pip, python-import

I'm a Python newbie. I have Python 3.8 installed, but my Macbook is running Python 2.7. I wasn't able to install Pip initially, but after looking up some Q&As,
I installed Pip using this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.2.3
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2

pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Following that, I installed some modules successfully:

```
pip install python-docx
Collecting python-docx
  Downloading python-docx-0.8.10.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.5 MB 2.4 MB/s 
Collecting lxml>=2.3.2
  Downloading lxml-4.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (4.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.6 MB 11.3 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: lxml, python-docx
    Running setup.py install for python-docx ... done
Successfully installed lxml-4.5.0 python-docx-0.8.10
```

I can't seem to import them into Python. The "Site Packages" folders are orange, compared to the rest which are grey. I have uploaded a picture below, you can take a look:

[image: Image of Error Message]

Here's the output for pip versions:

```
which -a pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip

which -a pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Could it be a project interpreter issue?
Some screenshots below:

**Project Layout**
[image: image 1]

**Project Interpreter**
[image: image 2]

**Virtual Environment**
[image: image 3]

It's not just this module, I can't import all the modules that I have installed using Pip. Please help me! Thanks!! :)

Comment: Please add the output of `which -a pip` and `which -a pip3` to the question.

Comment: Hi @DavidCullen, do you mean where's the module installed? It's here:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docx

Comment: No, I mean open a terminal window, run those commands, copy the output, and paste it into the question. I am trying to find out if you have multiple versions of `pip` installed and if you used the 2.7 `pip` to install the packages. However, the fact that the package is installed in 3.8 indicates that your IDE (PyCharm?) may be using 2.7 `python` as its interpreter. Another possibility is that you are using a 3.8 virtualenv, but you installed the packages to a system installed 3.8.

Comment: @DavidCullen thanks for the clarification! I have added the output, and also some info and images in the question..

Comment: It looks like you used the system installed `pip` 3.8, which installed them to `/Library`. You need to use the virtualenv `pip` so they get installed in the virtualenv.

Comment: @ser It seems you have created a virtual environment in PyCharm. Did you activate this before installing packages via `pip`? When you open a terminal from within PyCharm it will automatically activate the environment. Otherwise you need to run something like `conda activate Lesson202003`. As David mentioned, it seems you have installed the packages in the system Python. "Base interpreter" in the dialog only means that the virtual environment will be based off from that interpreter, not that they are actually shared.

Comment: You can run `source venv/bin/activate` in your `test` directory to activate the virtualenv. Then run the `pip` commands.

Comment: Hi @a_guest thanks for the feedback, yes I activated that before installing the packages.

Comment: @DavidCullen ok let me try that

Comment: @ser But it seems that you didn't activate it since `which pip` points to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip` which isn't the virtual environment.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks to both of your explanations, I got the concept and managed to import the modules. I guess I have to read up more about virtualenv before I screw up further! :p

Comment: @a_guest haha yes you're right, I didn't activate, I realised that. I followed David's commands and managed to do it!

Comment: @DavidCullen
If you like, please put the solution in the answer so I can pick it as the best answer and mark this question solved. Thank you! 
--> a_guest, thank you too!

Comment: @ser It is probably best if you self-answer. That way you can include screenshots of exactly what you did. Even though we are both on macos, my PyCharm setup looks completely different to yours.

Comment: For this kind of issues, always use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand` instead of `pip somecommand` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/)

Comment: ok @DavidCullen I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue with the help of @DavidCullen and @a_guest

So previously I have installed the modules on the system of my MacBook, but in PyCharm, I was actually in the Virtual Environment. These two didn't link.

After I understood the concept, there are two ways to sort the issue - 
1. suggested by @DavidCullen -- run `source venv/bin/activate` in the Terminal in PyCharm, and then use the Pip commands

2. I was playing around PyCharm and found this option to "Activate Global Site Packages" -- 
   [image]

I was able to import my installed modules after these.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i also faced the same problem previously to get out of the problem install it in the powershell or cmd or the place where you are executing the code.
this has worked for me.